# Xamarin Forms very slow build time on iOS from Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a CRM app using

- Xamarin Forms 2.3.3.180
- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
- Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.2.2.11
- Xamarin iOS 10.3.1.8
- Other components (syncfusion, devexpress, acr, servicestack, etc...)

Building all the projects begins to be really long and heavy.
Now when I build in debug, attached to a device, It takes more than 9 minutes!!!

Someone have got similar issue and can help me? 
What can I do or check to reduce build time?

I have set build output verbosity to Diagnostic, this is the summary:

```
8>Target Performance Summary:
8>        0 ms  PrepareResourceNames                       1 calls
8>        0 ms  _OptimizePngImages                         1 calls
8>        0 ms  Compile                                    1 calls
8>        0 ms  ModifyUnitTestPlatformVersion              1 calls
8>        0 ms  ResolveSDKReferences                       1 calls
8>        0 ms  CreateIpa                                  1 calls
8>        0 ms  _OptimizePropertyLists                     1 calls
8>        0 ms  _ReadCompileImageAssets                    1 calls
8>        0 ms  AfterRebuild                               1 calls
8>        0 ms  DesignTimeXamlMarkupCompilation            1 calls
8>        0 ms  SetWin32ManifestProperties                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  BeforeCodesign                             1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CopyAppExtensionsToBundle                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CoreOptimizeLocalizationFiles             1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CompileTextureAtlases                     1 calls
8>        0 ms  Clean                                      1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CodesignFrameworks                        1 calls
8>        0 ms  _GenerateSatelliteAssemblyInputs           1 calls
8>        0 ms  CleanReferencedProjects                    1 calls
8>        0 ms  _OptimizeLocalizationFiles                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  _ResolveUniversalTypeIdentifiers           1 calls
8>        0 ms  ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  _SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties        1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CodesignNativeLibraries                   1 calls
8>        0 ms  _ResolveAppExtensionReferences             1 calls
8>        0 ms  _SetMtouchProjectDirectory                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  Archive                                    1 calls
8>        0 ms  CreateCustomManifestResourceNames          1 calls
8>        0 ms  _BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets           3 calls
8>        0 ms  _CoreCompileTextureAtlases                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryXamlAppDefs        5 calls
8>        0 ms  BeforeCompile                              1 calls
8>        0 ms  AfterCompile                               1 calls
8>        0 ms  AfterBuild                                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  GetTargetPath                              5 calls
8>        0 ms  _SplitWatchAppReferencesByExistent         1 calls
8>        0 ms  BeforeRebuild                              1 calls
8>        0 ms  _SetTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute        1 calls
8>        0 ms  _BeforeCoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions     1 calls
8>        0 ms  Build                                      1 calls
8>        0 ms  _PrepareResourceRules                      1 calls
8>        0 ms  InjectReference_f0961790-64cb-4db0-9ef7-5ca95aee54f3   1 calls
8>        0 ms  DeleteBuildInfoResource                    1 calls
8>        0 ms  ExpressionBuildExtension                   1 calls
8>        0 ms  AfterResGen                                1 calls
8>        0 ms  ValidationExtension                        1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CoreCompileSceneKitAssets                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CompileInterfaceDefinitions               1 calls
8>        0 ms  CleanPublishFolder                         1 calls
8>        0 ms  _ResolveWatchAppReferences                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  AfterCodesign                              1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CoreOptimizePropertyLists                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  PrepareRdlFiles                            1 calls
8>        0 ms  AfterClean                                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  DeleteBuildInfoFile                        1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CompileSceneKitAssets                     1 calls
8>        0 ms  PrepareForRun                              1 calls
8>        0 ms  SetBuildInfoDefaults                       1 calls
8>        0 ms  BeforeClean                                1 calls
8>        0 ms  ResolveReferences                          1 calls
8>        0 ms  Codesign                                   1 calls
8>        0 ms  CoreCodesign                               1 calls
8>        0 ms  AfterResolveReferences                     1 calls
8>        0 ms  _GenerateFrameworkDebugSymbols             1 calls
8>        0 ms  PrepareResources                           1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory          1 calls
8>        0 ms  CompileRdlFiles                            1 calls
8>        0 ms  GetFrameworkPaths                          1 calls
8>        0 ms  BeforeResolveReferences                    1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CompileColladaAssets                      1 calls
8>        0 ms  BeforeResGen                               1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CompileImageAssets                        1 calls
8>        0 ms  _GenerateBundleName                        1 calls
8>        0 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          1 calls
8>        0 ms  EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports             1 calls
8>        0 ms  _SplitAppExtensionReferencesByExistent     1 calls
8>        0 ms  ExpandSDKReferences                        1 calls
8>        0 ms  _SeparateAppExtensionReferences            1 calls
8>        0 ms  _ComputeTargetArchitectures                1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CoreCompileColladaAssets                  1 calls
8>        0 ms  CreateSatelliteAssemblies                  1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CoreXamlG                                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  Rebuild                                    1 calls
8>        0 ms  ResGen                                     1 calls
8>        0 ms  BeforeBuild                                1 calls
8>        0 ms  CoreBuild                                  1 calls
8>        0 ms  _CreateAppBundle                           1 calls
8>        0 ms  _DownloadNuGet                             1 calls
8>        0 ms  XamlG                                      1 calls
8>        1 ms  CleanXsdCodeGen                            1 calls
8>        1 ms  _CheckForInvalidTargetFrameworkProfile     7 calls
8>        1 ms  _ReadCoreCompileSceneKitAssets             1 calls
8>        1 ms  _BeforeCoreCompileImageAssets              1 calls
8>        1 ms  GetInstalledSDKLocations                   1 calls
8>        1 ms  _CleanUploaded                             1 calls
8>        1 ms  PreXsdCodeGen                              1 calls
8>        1 ms  _SeparateWatchAppReferences                1 calls
8>        1 ms  SplitResourcesByCulture                    1 calls
8>        1 ms  CoreResGen                                 1 calls
8>        1 ms  GetNativeManifest                          4 calls
8>        1 ms  _GenerateCompileInputs                     1 calls
8>        1 ms  _ReadCoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions       1 calls
8>        1 ms  _ReadCoreCompileTextureAtlases             1 calls
8>        1 ms  _CheckForCompileOutputs                    1 calls
8>        1 ms  _CollectXamlFiles                          1 calls
8>        1 ms  _CopyWatchOS2AppsToBundle                  1 calls
8>        1 ms  _CollectPropertyLists                      1 calls
8>        2 ms  _CollectLocalizationFiles                  1 calls
8>        2 ms  GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute    1 calls
8>        2 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  1 calls
8>        2 ms  _ParseExtraMtouchArgs                      1 calls
8>        2 ms  _PreXamlG                                  1 calls
8>        3 ms  GenerateCompiledExpressionsTempFile        1 calls
8>        3 ms  _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence     5 calls
8>        4 ms  _BeforeCompileTextureAtlases               3 calls
8>        4 ms  _DetectAppManifest                         1 calls
8>        4 ms  _CollectAssemblies                         1 calls
8>        4 ms  PrepareForBuild                            1 calls
8>        4 ms  _CollectColladaAssets                      1 calls
8>        4 ms  CopyFilesToMacOutputDirectory              1 calls
8>        5 ms  _CollectPngImages                          1 calls
8>        5 ms  CopyFilesToOutputDirectory                 1 calls
8>        5 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   8 calls
8>        9 ms  _CoreCompileImageAssets                    1 calls
8>       11 ms  _GenerateBuildSessionId                    1 calls
8>       12 ms  GetBundleResourceWithLogicalNameItems      1 calls
8>       21 ms  _AfterCoreOptimizePngImages                1 calls
8>       24 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 8 calls
8>       26 ms  _CreatePkgInfo                             1 calls
8>       26 ms  _CreateDebugConfiguration                  1 calls
8>       26 ms  AssignTargetPaths                          5 calls
8>       27 ms  CheckPrerequisites                         1 calls
8>       28 ms  _CreateAssetPackManifest                   1 calls
8>       31 ms  _DetectDebugNetworkConfiguration           1 calls
8>       33 ms  IncrementalClean                           1 calls
8>       38 ms  _EmbedMobileProvision                      1 calls
8>       39 ms  _ValidateAppBundle                         1 calls
8>       40 ms  _CollectFrameworks                         1 calls
8>       47 ms  _CopyITunesArtwork                         1 calls
8>       53 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              5 calls
8>       54 ms  ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades          1 calls
8>       79 ms  _CompileEntitlements                       1 calls
8>      101 ms  _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites         1 calls
8>      112 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                   1 calls
8>      119 ms  _GetNativeExecutableName                   1 calls
8>      127 ms  _DetectSdkLocations                        1 calls
8>      132 ms  _CreateDebugSettings                       1 calls
8>      141 ms  XamlC                                      1 calls
8>      167 ms  _CollectITunesArtwork                      1 calls
8>      182 ms  _ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths          1 calls
8>      193 ms  _DetectSigningIdentity                     1 calls
8>      203 ms  _CompileAppManifest                        1 calls
8>      224 ms  _CleanDeviceSpecificOutput                 1 calls
8>      329 ms  _CleanDebugSymbols                         1 calls
8>      345 ms  _CollectBundleResources                    1 calls
8>      357 ms  CoreClean                                  1 calls
8>      377 ms  _CleanAppBundle                            1 calls
8>      393 ms  RestorePackages                            1 calls
8>      406 ms  _CopyResourcesToBundle                     1 calls
8>      535 ms  _CleanMacBuild                             1 calls
8>      578 ms  _CleanITunesArtwork                        1 calls
8>      613 ms  GetBuiltProjectOutputRecursive             8 calls
8>      744 ms  _ConvertDebuggingFiles                     1 calls
8>      906 ms  _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal                  1 calls
8>      954 ms  CoreCompile                                1 calls
8>      991 ms  ResolveAssemblyReferences                  1 calls
8>     2125 ms  _SayGoodbye                                1 calls
8>     2690 ms  _SayHello                                  1 calls
8>     3122 ms  _CleanIntermediateToolOutput               1 calls
8>     5962 ms  _UnpackLibraryResources                    1 calls
8>     6088 ms  _CoreOptimizePngImages                     1 calls
8>     6670 ms  CopyIpaFromMac                             1 calls
8>     9556 ms  _CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions           1 calls
8>    10048 ms  _CoreCreateIpa                             1 calls
8>    11692 ms  _ZipIpa                                    1 calls
8>    11778 ms  _CodesignAppBundle                         1 calls
8>    15093 ms  _CodesignVerify                            1 calls
8>    16257 ms  CopyDSYMFromMac                            1 calls
8>    25191 ms  _GenerateDebugSymbols                      1 calls
8>    46092 ms  _CompileITunesMetadata                     1 calls
8>    384931 ms  _CompileToNative                           1 calls
8>
8>Task Performance Summary:
8>        0 ms  ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet                 1 calls
8>        0 ms  FindAppConfigFile                          1 calls
8>        0 ms  GetFrameworkPath                           1 calls
8>        1 ms  CallTarget                                 1 calls
8>        1 ms  AssignCulture                              1 calls
8>        1 ms  ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput             1 calls
8>        1 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  1 calls
8>        1 ms  FixedCreateCSharpManifestResourceName      1 calls
8>        2 ms  ParseExtraMtouchArgs                       1 calls
8>        2 ms  Message                                   18 calls
8>        3 ms  CollectMonotouchReferences                 1 calls
8>        4 ms  FindItemWithLogicalName                    1 calls
8>        4 ms  CopyFilesToBuildServer                     1 calls
8>        5 ms  ReadLinesFromFile                          2 calls
8>        8 ms  ConvertToAbsolutePath                      1 calls
8>        9 ms  GenerateBuildSessionId                     1 calls
8>       11 ms  AssignTargetPath                          30 calls
8>       19 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 8 calls
8>       21 ms  WriteItemsToFile                           3 calls
8>       21 ms  CreateItem                               129 calls
8>       25 ms  CreatePkgInfo                              1 calls
8>       26 ms  CreateDebugConfiguration                   1 calls
8>       28 ms  CreateAssetPackManifest                    1 calls
8>       31 ms  DetectDebugNetworkConfiguration            1 calls
8>       38 ms  EmbedMobileProvision                       1 calls
8>       38 ms  ValidateAppBundleTask                      1 calls
8>       40 ms  CollectFrameworks                          1 calls
8>       49 ms  FindUnderPath                              7 calls
8>       51 ms  RemoveDuplicates                           3 calls
8>       74 ms  WriteLinesToFile                          13 calls
8>       79 ms  CompileEntitlements                        1 calls
8>       86 ms  CompileAppManifest                         1 calls
8>      118 ms  DetectSdkLocations                         1 calls
8>      119 ms  GetNativeExecutableName                    1 calls
8>      131 ms  CreateDebugSettings                        1 calls
8>      140 ms  XamlCTask                                  1 calls
8>      167 ms  CollectITunesArtwork                       1 calls
8>      181 ms  ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths           1 calls
8>      193 ms  DetectSigningIdentity                      1 calls
8>      348 ms  CollectBundleResources                     2 calls
8>      385 ms  SmartCopy                                  1 calls
8>      393 ms  Exec                                       1 calls
8>      665 ms  ConvertPdbToMdb                            1 calls
8>      712 ms  MsBuild                                   12 calls
8>      952 ms  Csc                                        1 calls
8>      990 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   1 calls
8>     1258 ms  Copy                                      21 calls
8>     1488 ms  Delete                                    14 calls
8>     2125 ms  SayGoodbye                                 1 calls
8>     2537 ms  LocalUnzip                                 1 calls
8>     2690 ms  SayHello                                   1 calls
8>     3053 ms  Ditto                                      1 calls
8>     3329 ms  MakeDir                                    5 calls
8>     3408 ms  CollectITunesSourceFiles                   1 calls
8>     4600 ms  RemoveDir                                  9 calls
8>     5961 ms  UnpackLibraryResources                     1 calls
8>     6074 ms  OptimizeImage                              1 calls
8>     8126 ms  SpotlightIndexer                           1 calls
8>     9474 ms  CopyFileFromMac                            2 calls
8>     9544 ms  IBTool                                     1 calls
8>    11777 ms  Codesign                                   1 calls
8>    15093 ms  CodesignVerify                             1 calls
8>    16798 ms  DSymUtil                                   1 calls
8>    22417 ms  Zip                                        2 calls
8>    46092 ms  CompileITunesMetadata                      1 calls
8>    384918 ms  MTouch                                     1 calls
8>
8>Build succeeded.
8>
8>Time Elapsed 00:09:26.72
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/ios-build-mechanics/#Device_Tricks
Maybe this would help you?

Comment: Building for iOS device is always a pain from VS. Did you enable incremental build in the projects options?

Comment: Try using xamarin live player. It's super fast with almost no delay. You need vs 2017.4+ and its app from apple store. If you register in iOS's test flight, you can download its beta app which is far better than the one you can download from app store. As a matter of fact, the apple store's public version is really limited. My app runs in less than 1 second! Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Give Visual Studio 2017 for Mac a try. I was having build times like 5 minutes for my Xamarin.Forms iOS app in VS2015 on Windows.
 Now using VS for Mac to build the same project takes about 20 - 40 seconds.
Vs 2015 is on a Windows 10 VM running on my 2011 MBP.
VS for mac on the same MBP.

Comment: yepp, i'm just trying now and despite my windows pc is much powerful than my mac, my xamarin.forms ios projects are way faster to debug directly on mac